# Mapbox clear route polyline

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

i can draw polyline route on map but i cannot clear this route from mapview. My code is:

```
func drawRoute() {
    var routeCoordinates = route.coordinates!
    let polyline = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: &routeCoordinates, count: route.coordinateCount)
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "polyline", features: [polyline], options: nil)
    style.addSource(source)
    let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline", source: source)
    layer.lineJoin = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: NSValue(mglLineJoin: .round))
    layer.lineCap = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: NSValue(mglLineCap: .round))
    layer.lineColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor(red: 31 / 255, green: 31 / 255, blue: 31 / 255, alpha: 1))
    layer.lineWidth = MGLStyleValue(interpolationMode: .exponential, cameraStops: [14: MGLStyleValue<NSNumber>(rawValue: 2), 18: MGLStyleValue<NSNumber>(rawValue: 20)], options: [.defaultValue : MGLConstantStyleValue<NSNumber>(rawValue: 1.5)])
    let casingLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline-case", source: source)
    casingLayer.lineJoin = layer.lineJoin
    casingLayer.lineCap = layer.lineCap
    casingLayer.lineGapWidth = layer.lineWidth
    casingLayer.lineColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: UIColor(red: 0 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 0 / 255, alpha: 1))
    casingLayer.lineWidth = MGLStyleValue(interpolationMode: .exponential, cameraStops: [14: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 1), 18: MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 4)], options: [.defaultValue : MGLConstantStyleValue<NSNumber>(rawValue: 1.5)])
    let dashedLayer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline-dash", source: source)
    dashedLayer.lineJoin = layer.lineJoin
    dashedLayer.lineCap = layer.lineCap
    dashedLayer.lineColor = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: .white)
    dashedLayer.lineOpacity = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: 1.0)
    dashedLayer.lineWidth = layer.lineWidth
    dashedLayer.lineDashPattern = MGLStyleValue(rawValue: [0, 1.5])
    style.addLayer(layer)
    style.addLayer(dashedLayer)
    style.insertLayer(casingLayer, below: layer)
}
```

I want to clear this polyline and redraw with different coordinates. I tried removeAnnotation method but it didn't help. Thanks.

Comment: i never use mapview it's my guessing try to create a new polyline object inside function then declare the value

Comment: Its too early to ask question as you found the solution just less than an hour.

Comment: I have been searching more than 6 hours and found the answer on slack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. We can reach source with identifier like `self.mapView.style?.source(withIdentifier: "polyline")` and then remove it.

Comment: You should put then full answer how to remove it, not just a line how to get source

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
if let source = mapView.style?.source(withIdentifier: "polyline") as? MGLShapeSource {

        source.shape = nil
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I was dealing with almost the same problem. I needed to clean the map and add another polyline.
 My code to create a polyline

```
 let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: randomIdentifier, shape: nil, options: nil)

    self.mapView.style?.addSource(source)
    self.polylineSource = source

    let layer = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "polyline", source: source)
```

The error said:

> 'MGLRedundantSourceIdentifierException', reason: 'Source polyline
>   already exists'.

So, i found out there is no easy method to remove a polyline.
I created a random string to add to the identifier of the polyline everytime it creates a new one to solve this problem

```
func randomString(length: Int) -> String {
    let letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String((0..<length).map{ _ in letters.randomElement()! })
}
```

...

```
func drawRoute(route: Route){

    let randomIdentifier = randomString(length: 8)
    print("random identifier \(randomIdentifier)")

    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: randomIdentifier, shape: nil, options: nil)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use identifier as a random unique identifier because identifier is not remove completely when we remove by mapView.style?.removeSource(source) So use below method to generate random identifier.

```
private func randomIdentifier(length: Int) -> String {
    let identifier = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
    return String((0..<length).map{ _ in identifier.randomElement()! })
}
```

and use it

```
func drawPolyLine(coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], color: Double, index: Int) {

    let polyline = MGLPolylineFeature(coordinates: coordinates, count: UInt(coordinates.count))

    let randomIdentifierToken = randomIdentifier(length: index)
    
    // If there's already a route line on the map, reset its shape to the new route
    let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "route-source-\(randomIdentifierToken)", features: [polyline], options: nil)
    
        // Customize the route line color and width
        let lineStyle = MGLLineStyleLayer(identifier: "route-style-\(randomIdentifierToken)", source: source)
        lineStyle.lineWidth = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 5)

        if color == 1 {
            let color = UIColor(rgb: APPCOLOR.kPolylineOrangeColor)
            lineStyle.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: color)
        } else if color == 3 {
            let color = UIColor(rgb: APPCOLOR.kPolylineRedColor)
            lineStyle.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: color)
        } else {
            let color = UIColor(rgb: APPCOLOR.kPolylineBlueColor)
            lineStyle.lineColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: color)
        }

        // Add the source and style layer of the route line to the map
        mapView.style?.addSource(source)
        mapView.style?.addLayer(lineStyle)

        // store identifers to clear from map when requried
        polylineIdentifiers.append(source.identifier)
        polylineIdentifiers.append(lineStyle.identifier)

}
```